# Checkbox validation within wordpress for a paypal button

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I am trying to get a simple Terms and Conditions checkbox to validate before a user is allowed to click a paypal button.  I currently have this code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> 

    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="my email"> 

    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> 

    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="15-minutes"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">  
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"> 

    <!-- Display the payment button. --> 
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"alt="stuff"> 
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" > 
</form>
```

Any help or guidance would be super helpful.

Festivus for the rest of us,

Tom

Answer (score 1):

A little jQuery like this should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/mVK4r/

I added a terms and conditions checkbox and then tested to see if it's checked. If it is, the button behaves normally. If it is not, there's an alert prompting the user to accept the terms and the button won't work.

Hope this helps - good luck!

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> 

<!-- Terms and Conditions check box -->
<p><input type="checkbox" id="terms"> Yes, I accept the terms and conditions</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. --> 
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="my email"> 

<!-- Specify a Buy Now button. --> 
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> 

<!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. --> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="15-minutes"> 
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">  
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"> 

<!-- Display the payment button. --> 
<input type="image" id="button" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="stuff"> 
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" > 
</form>  ​

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(e){
        if ($('#terms').prop('checked') == false) {
            alert('Please accept the terms and conditions');
            e.preventDefault();  
    }
    else {
       // Allow the button the do its thing
        }
    });
});​
</script>
```